# OpenAM With Maven

Tags: java, maven, openam

I am trying to download OpenAM through Maven dependencies as stated on this website:

https://wikis.forgerock.org/confluence/display/openam/Using+Maven+and+OpenAM

Below is Maven pom.xml file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven 4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>OpenAMExample</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>OpenAMExample</name>

  <properties>
     <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
     <openam.version>10.1.0-Xpress</openam.version>
  </properties> 

  <dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.forgerock.openam</groupId>
    <artifactId>openam-core</artifactId>
    <version>${openam.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.forgerock.openam</groupId>
    <artifactId>openam-shared</artifactId>
    <version>${openam.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.forgerock.openam</groupId>
    <artifactId>openam-federation-library</artifactId>
    <version>${openam.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.forgerock.openam</groupId>
    <artifactId>openam-clientsdk</artifactId>
    <version>${openam.version}</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>junit</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
          <version>3.8.1</version>
          <scope>test</scope>
      </dependency>
     </dependencies>

  <repositories>
<repository>
    <id>forgerock</id>
    <url>http://maven.forgerock.org/repo/releases</url>
</repository>
  </repositories>
</project>
```

I cannot download this, there seems to be problems. It mentions missing artifact for each artifact within OpenAM.

Having researched on Google no one seems to have any problems.

Any ideas why?

EDIT

```
BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.305s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Aug 05 16:01:44 BST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 2M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project OpenAMExample: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.webchannel.example:OpenAMExample:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.forgerock.openam:openam-core:jar:10.1.0-Xpress, org.forgerock.openam:openam-shared:jar:10.1.0-Xpress, org.forgerock.openam:openam-federation-library:jar:10.1.0-Xpress, org.forgerock.openam:openam-clientsdk:jar:10.1.0-Xpress: Failure to find org.forgerock.openam:openam-core:jar:10.1.0-Xpress in http://nexus.example.private:8081/content/groups/public was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles: 
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

EDIT 2:

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building OpenAMExample 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
 [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[WARNING] The POM for com.sun.web.ui:cc_zh_HK:jar:2008-08-08 is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading: http://nexus.example.private:8081/content/groups/public/com/sun/web/ui/cc_zh_TW/2008-08-08/cc_zh_TW-2008-08-08.pom

[WARNING] The POM for com.sun.web.ui:cc_zh_TW:jar:2008-08-08 is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading: http://nexus.example.private:8081/content/groups/public/external/esapiport/2009-26-07/esapiport-2009-26-07.pom

 [WARNING] The POM for external:esapiport:jar:2009-26-07 is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading: http://nexus.example.private:8081/content/groups/public/external/sleepycat-je/2011-04-07/sleepycat-je-2011-04-07.pom

[WARNING] The POM for external:webservices-rt:jar:2009-29-07 is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 42.038s
[INFO] Finished at: Mon Aug 05 16:31:52 BST 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/15M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project OpenAMExample: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.webchannel.example:OpenAMExample:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies for [org.forgerock.openam:openam-core:jar:10.1.0-Xpress (compile), org.forgerock.openam:openam-shared:jar:10.1.0-Xpress (compile), org.forgerock.openam:openam-federation-library:jar:10.1.0-Xpress (compile), org.forgerock.openam:openam-clientsdk:jar:10.1.0-Xpress (compile), junit:junit:jar:3.8.1 (test)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.forgerock.opendj:opendj-server:jar:2.4.6: Could not find artifact org.forgerock.opendj:opendj-project:pom:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT in nexus (http://nexus.example.private:8081/content/groups/public) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Comment: Are you working behind a company proxy? Do you use direct connection to maven repositories or using a repository manager? You probably need to add the repository you noted in your pom to the settings.xml or to the repository manager.

Comment: I have direct connection to Maven repositories.

Comment: So did you add the repository to your settings.xml?

Comment: please add the maven install log  .. to show people exactly the error you have

Comment: Yes, I have done this.

Comment: do 'mvn install > log.txt' and paste the log here

Comment: Please see log above in edit section.

Answer (score 0):

it says was cached in the local repository

Go to $HOME/.m2/repository/org/ and remove forgerock  directory and try again

you might had a connection error or something like that

another way is to try  right click > maven > maven update if you use m2e and check force updating release

Comment: I aksed the administrator and he added the repository to Nexus. After this everything started to download as in EDIT 2. Not sure what the problem is now.

Comment: This is another error ... ask him to add org.forgerock.opendj:opendj-project:pom:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT to the repo

Comment: Well, he added the original one to the repository section. Where will he add this other one? This is not a repository is it?

Comment: try using   <openam.version>10.0.0</openam.version>

Comment: Maven is unable to find 10.0.0 in Nexus.

Comment: Well, ask the admin of nexus to add http://maven.forgerock.org/repo/releases to nexus repositories. like this http://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/reference/config-sect-new-repo.html

Comment: The opendj-project 3.0.0-SNAPSHOT artifact is under the maven.forgerock.org/repo/snapshots/ repository, you should add that to your Nexus configuration.

Answer (score 0):

the dependency 
of OpenSSOclientsdk, at the moment, is not found in any maven  repository. Therefore,
you must include in your local repository:

{dir maven repo}/com/sun/identity/OpenSSOclientsdk/8.0/OpenSSOclientsdk-8.0.jar.

Then, you can execute

```
$ mvn install
```

And the provider will be located in

{dir maven repo}/com/sun/identity/provider/springsecurity/0.1/springsecurity-0.1.jar

to be used in maven projects. (See more details in http://maven.apache.org)